# How do I assign values to checkboxes from an ArrayList

Tags: c#

I hope you're well.
I want to get the data from my Access database and assign each row to a checkbox in a form in c#. So, I have read the data from the database to an arraylist. Now, I do not know how exactly I can assign those values to the checkboxes from the ArrayList.
I thought I could just say:
checkbox1.Text = Cakes(0);
but it is saying that I need a method.
Please assist me.

Here is the code that I have so far.

```
public partial class Customer : Form
{
    private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    public Customer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=FILE PATH;Persist Security Info=False;";
    }

    private void Customer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * Cakes";
            List<string> Cakes = new List<string>();
            using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Cakes.Add(reader["Product Name"].ToString());
                }
            }
            checkBox1.Text = Cakes(0);
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the while loop add all the values to the `Cakes` list, after that assign the list as the `CheckBox` text, based on the code example (notice the `Cakes[0]`), also put the `connection` in a using statement so it's disposed and closed (removed the `connection.Close()` and moved the reader):

```
private void Customer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * Cakes";
        List<string> Cakes = new List<string>();
        using (connection)
        {
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Cakes.Add(reader["Product Name"].ToString());
            }
        }
        checkBox1.Text = Cakes[0];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: The values are coming from the database, haven't I already done what you are saying?

Comment: Yes but your code is using `checkBox1.Text = Cakes(0);` with round brackets, the List accessor needs to be with square brackets `checkBox1.Text = Cakes[0];`

Comment: Oh right, I'm so sorry about that. Let me try that. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, what if I want the checkboxes to display 2 colums from the database together, how would I do that?

Comment: @Batflash why did you remove the accepted answer? did it answer your original question? If you have a new question you should post it, if this answer was accepted and answered this question then accept it (removing an accept is just bad conduct)

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I have a question relating to the same question that I had asked and I did not realise it until later. I'm really sorry, I'm new to Stack Overflow. I'm really sorry.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please read this

Comment: no problem, you can ask a new question for the new issue